# Can you use the pounce ability during a surprise round

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat

I remember reading that during a surprise round you can only take a single action. A charge is usually a full round action but can be used if you are restricted to a single action, as stated [in the special attack rules on charge](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#charge). Since the pounce ability says that you can full attack during a charge, can you use it to full attack during a surprise round? The pounce description in the MM (p313) is as follows:

> Pounce (Ex): When a creature with this special attack makes a
>   charge, it can follow with a full attack—including rake attacks if
>   the creature also has the rake ability.

My opinion is that you should be able to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As written, I would say yes: you have made a charge, since there's no longer any such thing as a "partial charge" in 3.5. This is another reason why Pounce is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This works exactly as you describe it.